# How to show Magnifier On a PopUp Image Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have some thumbnails .. and i when

i click on that thumbnail Image will get enlarge in a PopUp

I want to show magnifier in that to zoom the areas of the image

Is is possible to show magnifier in popup image

Comment: plz share the code you have developed

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. If you bind your function to show the magnifier when the user hovers over the image you should get the effect that you have in mind.

```
$(popUp).mouseenter(showMagnifier).mouseleave(hideMagnifier)
```